# Create action when textfield is touched

Tags: ios, textfield

I need to give action while touching on the textfield. I have imported Material to give some effects for the UI designs animations. I need to display the view while touching the textfield.But I get error as :unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fed2b046800'
*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to add the target ( plus it's not the correct way to add selectors )

```
 self.dobField.addTarget(self, action:Selector(("textFieldDidBeginEditing")), for: UIControlEvents.editingDidBegin)
```

you need only

```
self.dobField.delegate = self
```

with

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField){}
```

//

right selector would be

```
self.dobField.addTarget(self, action:#selector(someMethod), for: UIControlEvents.editingDidBegin)
```

with

```
@objc func someMethod(_ textField: UITextField){}
```

BTW you already conform  to `UITextFieldDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this buy setting the making your view controller conform to `UITextFieldDelegate`, and setting your text field's `delegate` to be the view controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dobField.delegate = self // or do this in your storyboard
}
```

and then handle your action in one of these 2 methods…

```
extension EditProfileViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool 

        return true // or return false if you don't want to actually edit the field
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)

    }
}
```